# jquery draggable enable and disable

Tags: jquery, draggable

Ive tried anything to do this, but always get the same error

```
$(".tooltip").draggable('disable');
```

Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

Prior to initialization? So I cannot remove the option before its actually being dragged around? Ive tried with droppable as well, cant seem to get them disabled enabled without getting this error.

edit:
I found out that I have an element with the class that is without draggable (which makes sense when you look at the error). Now I just have to find a way so it disables all the draggables without throwing the error :)

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

Comment: disable must be called in this way $("#draggable").draggable({ disabled: true }); http://jsfiddle.net/3Lrg2/23/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".tooltip").draggable({ disabled: true });
```

This initializes the draggable in the disabled state. You can then use

```
$(".tooltip").draggable("enable");
```

later when you want to allow dragging.

Comment: $(".tooltip").draggable({ disabled: false}); //works to re-enable.

Comment: @Reid I don't think so. jQuery UI widgets only use options when initializing. To change an existing widget you use methods.

Comment: @Barmar Well I will merely state that it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to recreate your scenario in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dboots/NDZKY/

This is using

```
$('.draggable').draggable('disable');
```

and

```
$('.draggable').draggable('enable');
```

Is there something different that you're not able to do the same? Looks like you have the same syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

and a example here:

```
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
```

Have you "included" jquery-ui.js library?

try on this fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/3Lrg2/23/

Comment: this should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

Use **one button** to **enable** and **disable**

```
$("#container").draggable({disabled:false});
$("#container").draggable({disabled:true});
```

Simple Example Given Below:

```
<div id = "container"></div>
<button id = "control"></button>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("#control").click(function()
          {
            if($("#control").hasClass("active")
              {
                $("container").draggable({disabled:true});
                $("control").removeAttr("class","active");   
              }
            else
              {
                $("container").draggable({disabled:false});
                $("control").attr("class","active");
              }
          });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try using .unbind('ondrag') to remove the event from your element.

sorry I think it should be $("tooltip").unbind('draggable') not 100% sure on event name.