# Making element draggable after toggleClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggleclass

My goal is to make an element draggable using jQuery UI if it has a certain class present. The class is added using toggleClass on dblclick.

Adding the 'draggable' class to the right element on double click:

```
    $("article.spread").dblclick(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("draggable");
    });
```

Then I use this to make the element draggable:

```
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
```

Only it will not work. The toggleClass is successful but it isn't draggable.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13630121/588973

Comment: You could just replace the `.toggleClass(...)` with `.draggable()`. On a related note, keep in mind that initialising the same widget on the same element multiple times is perfectly valid and will behave in the expected way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the class dynamically after the first drggable is fired on your elements and will not live evalueted.

You can add the drggable when you are adding the class and enable/disable it if it's already attached:

```
$("article.spread").dblclick(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("draggable");
    if ($(this).data('draggable')) {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'disabled') ? $(this).draggable('enable') : $(this).draggable('disable');
    } else {
        $(this).draggable();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8J7sq/

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for. The only problem is that the element is still draggable after I remove the class by double clicking on the element the second time. How could I disable draggable again?

Comment: @adalsteinn the element is not draggable because of the disable on it, give a try and not confuse it with the text selection

Comment: My problem was that I was using the wrong jQuery/jQuery UI library. This works very well! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are declaring $(".draggable").draggable() and then add class to an element.

$(".draggable").draggable() will only make the current elements on page having draggable class draggable.

you can try something like

```
$("article.spread").dblclick(function() {
     if ($(this).data('draggable')) {
        $(this).draggable({ cancel: "div" });
        $(this).data('draggable', false);
     }
     else {
        $(this).draggable();
        $(this).data('draggable', true);
     }
});
```